# Rijndael PHP encode FLASH decode

Tags: php, security, rijndael

I am trying to pass some encrypted data to a flash , but I got stuck somewhere in the middle.

Im using RIJNDAEL algorithm to encode the data in PHP :

```
function encrypt($text){
    $key = "53cded30ff7ba54d65b939fd594e3d63";
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); //get vector size on CBC mode 
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); //Creating the vector
    $cryptedtext = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); //Encrypting using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 algorithm 
    return $cryptedtext;
}
```

And im using the AS3CRYPT library to decrypt the value in flash.

The problem is that if I try to decode the value in flash or even in the demo of AS3CRYPT, it doesnt work.

I also tried to return the data from PHP encoded with base64_encode but still not working.

The output from PHP is something like : `flashvar=Á žJcV—µg)7¾1´‘5{Ò<¶Ù$þS„§”`

Probably I did something wrong in the PHP ...

Comment: More likely you're using the wrong decrypt methodology in Flash. A good encryption algorithm doesn't tell if you something's wrong (e.g. wrong key phrase), you just get garbage back instead of what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't add any padding, which is likely needed.

You'll have to pad it manually, [take a look at this post on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#102428) which explains one method of achieving PKCS7 padding compatibility.

Beyond that, make sure you're setting the matching confidentiality mode (`CBC`) and cipher within "AS3CRYPTO".